# Массив в java

Tags: android, java

Здрасьте.
Изучаю android разработку, и возник один вопрос. Есть код:

```
String[] phonesHTC = new String[] {"Sensation", "Desire", "Wildfire", "Hero"};

    for (String phone : phonesHTC) {
                 m = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 m.put("phoneName", phone); // название телефона
                 childDataItem.add(m);
             }
```

Нужно сделать так:

```
String[] phonesHTC = new String[] {"Sensation", "Desire", "Wildfire", "Hero"};

int[] price = new int[] {30,40,50,60};

    for (String phone : phonesHTC) {
                m = new HashMap<String, String>();
                m.put("phoneName", phone); // название телефона
                m.put("Price",price); // цена телефона
                childDataItem.add(m);
            }
```

Вопрос: как добавить в условие цикла и price? Как переделать цикл?
Вообще, эта прилажка делает список, и в каждом пункте этого списка добавляет еще несколько пунктов. И задача соостоит в том, чтобы к моделе телефона добавить её цену.
m - это атрибуты элементов, т.е. был один атрибут - название телефона, и нужно, чтобы было два атрибута: название и его цена.

Comment: Неудачно я написал, т.к. HashMap только String, но это не суть (можно не цену, а, например, цвет (String массив)). Суть в том, что как переделать цикл под 2 условия.

Comment: На C# было бы

    var phonesAndPrices = new[]
    {
        new { name = "Sensation", price = 30 },
        new { name = "Desire", price = 40 }
        // ...
    };

    foreach (var pp in phonesAndPrices)
        childDataItem.add(
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "phoneName", pp.name },
                { "Price", pp.price }
            });

(ну или то же с LINQ). Как такое попроще сделать делается в Java, не нашёл.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо. Вроде бы работает. Но, мне кажется, как то еще проще можно.
Вообще, это из этого урока:http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/86-urok-45-spisok-derevo-expandablelistview.html
В конце урока последний абзац. Может я что-то не допонял?

Comment: Думаю, и правда должно быть можно проще. Но я не спец по Java, сорри. перекину комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> phonesAndPrices = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
phonesAndPrices.put("Sensation", 30);
phonesAndPrices.put("Desire", 40);
// ...
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : phonesAndPrices.entrySet())
{
    m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m.put("phoneName", e.getKey());
    m.put("Price", e.getValue());
    childDataItem.add(m);
}
```

Так будет работать для двух видов данных, для большего количества полей придётся извращаться. Или определить класс-контейнер данных:

```
class Container
{
    public Container(String name, int price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    public String Name;
    public int Price;
    // и т. д.
}

// ...
Container[] phonesHTC = new Container[] {
    new Container("Sensation", 40),
    new Container("Desire", 50),
    new Container("Wildfire", 60),
    new Container("Hero", 70)
};

for (Container phone : phonesHTC) {
    m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m.put("phoneName", phone.Name);
    m.put("Price", phone.Price);
    childDataItem.add(m);
}
```

Но это выглядит довольно тяжеловесно и enterprisey (как это по-русски?)

Ещё более некрасивый вариант:

```
String[] phonesHTC = new String[] {"Sensation", "Desire", "Wildfire", "Hero"};
int[] price = new int[] {30,40,50,60};

for (int i = 0; i < phonesHTC.length; i++) {
    m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m.put("phoneName", phonesHTC[i]);
    m.put("Price", price[i]);
    childDataItem.add(m);
}
```

Comment: Ладно, еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @compl: добавил ещё вариант.

Comment: @compl: и ещё один.

Comment: > Или определить класс-контейнер данных
> Но это выглядит довольно тяжеловесно и enterprisey

@VladD, но это путь ООП и Java в частности, создавать классы объектов с идентичными наборами свойств )

Comment: @Nofate: Если в этом суть ООП, то я противник ООП. :-)

Нет, ну правда, код должен быть эстетичен. Нагромождение ненужных классов для перекладывания данных отвратительно и превращает искусство программирования в отупляющий конвейер.

Ещё по теме, [классика](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Comment: @VladD, не-не-не. Никаких ООП-холиворов )